# How to handle mutually exclusive actions in RESTful services?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, concurrency

I'm working right now in two WebApi projects and in both of them we encountered the same problem: we have some set of actions `Actions` that cannot be performed if an action `A` is being performed, and vice-versa. So, for example, if any of those `Actions` are running right now and the user sends a request to action `A`, action `A` must wait those other actions to finish before running.

Coming from a stateful services background, our first thought was to use locks, although with much resistance. We created a singleton service that simply stores `object`s mapped to user Id's, which can in turn be used as locks.

Now, of course this poses some really tough problems, like:

(1) We'll have to force users to always talk to only one server instance, even when their requests are coming from different devices in different parts of the world, since locks aren't going to automagically span from one instance to another.

(2) Then we'll have to build our own [sub-optimal] load balancer. Our plan was to use Azure's built-in one.

So my question is: how do you elegantly handle this problem in a way that **doesn't hurt horizontal scalability** and, preferably, doesn't need a custom load balancing policy?

Answer (score 3):

One approach, though certainly not the only one, is to queue the request and respond with 202 (Accepted).  Typically, the response will also provide a URL that the client can then monitor to determine the status of the outstanding request.  Similarly, if there is a need to cancel the pending action, the client can DELETE that URL.

Edit: Putting the above explanation another way, suppose that every request to modify the shared resource was handled as follows:

1. Client makes the request
2. The front-end server(s) forwards the request to the back-end server where it is queued up for processing (no locking necessary).  Aside from obvious rejections (malformed request, unauthorized access, etc.), the front-end server(s) always accepts the request.  Whether the actual request will succeed or when the request will actually be processed is not important to the front-end server(s).

(Now, assuming that the client actually needs to know the result of the request...)

3. The front-end server returns a 202 (Accepted) response, which includes a URL. The URL effectively points to the status (and possibly result) of the associated request.
4. The client periodically polls the URL.  (The front-end server(s) are just reading back-end state, so it should be fast and require no locking.)
5. Eventually, the back-end server will process the actual request and update the request status as appropriate.
6. The client gets the updated state and acts accordingly.

The key points here are:

- Locks are not needed most of the time.  When they are needed, they
  should only be for very fast operations.
- The actual processing of the requests are serialized on the back-end.  This avoids the concurrency issue.
- Load balancing and scaling issues on the front-end are minimized because they are still just working with back-end resources.  The front-end servers do not need to coordinate with anything except the
  back-end.

Though not germane to the original question, one of the other advantages of this approach is that the "queued" requests effectively become a transaction history of the shared resource.

Comment: But by queueing wouldn't I run into the same problem as locking - that is, having to either force the user into using only one server instance or having to pass state around instances? With option 1, I have to build my own load balancer. Option 2 would arise a host of different problems and probably take too much bandwidth.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a little be more detail.  Admittedly, it's still fairly generic, but hopefully it provides enough explanation for you to figure out if you can apply it to your particular situation.

Comment: Would the "queue" likely be a database so that the request and its state are accessible from multiple load-balanced servers?

Comment: @ScottHannen A database could certainly be one approach.  Each request is INSERTed into a table, where an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER is used to do the actual processing.  The URL returned by the 202 (Accepted) response allows the client to GET the status of that record.

Answer (score 1):

You can route to any server as long as they all use some concurrency control mechanism that excludes running critical operations concurrently. That mechanism could be a distributed lock (zookeeper, etcd, redis, hazelcast etc.) or a centralized lock (e.g. a particular server used for locking only, a db, a tuned memcached cluster). Your server can then either wait to respond to the REST client while waiting on a lock or you can implement the policy suggested in seairth's answer. I won't say it won't affect scalability at all, but if the critical sections are short and collisions are rare, all your servers that receive requests will be busy most of the time.